# Show alert message when duplicate values are present in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handsontable

I have a two columns as shown in fig. when i clicked **right** button the selected field will go to 2nd column but i have 4 fields which is already coming from database and now if i move First Name to 2nd column it will also accept that but i need to show error message as "duplicates are not allowed" if there is already selected value

[image]

```
  "click #lstBox1 > option": function(e){            
        var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox1 option:selected');
        if (selectedOpts.length == 0) {
            alert("Nothing to move.");
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $('#lstBox2').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $(e.target).text();            
        var result = this.data.filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.columnsexpo === text;
        });
        if (_.isEmpty(result)) {
            this.data.push({columnsexpo: text, placeholder: true });
            this.tab.handsontable("loadData", this.data);
            console.log(this.data);
        }
    },
  "click #lstBox2 > option": function(e){
        var selectedOpts = $('#lstBox2 option:selected');            
        $('#lstBox1').append($(selectedOpts).clone());
        $(selectedOpts).remove();
        e.preventDefault();
        var text = $(e.target).text();
       // console.log(text);
        var result = this.data.filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.columnsexpo === text;
        });

            this.data.pop({ columnsexpo: text, placeholder: true });
            this.tab.handsontable("loadData", this.data);
            console.log(this.data);

    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to recreate an ugly looking copy of your code.

What my code does is, on `button click` it gets the `span element` which was `clicked`.

This element is then stored inside a `variable and removed from the left side div`.

All the `text data in span` present in the `right side div` is taken and stored inside an `array`.

The text of the `selected span` from `left div` is compared to the text present in all the `spans` in the `right div`.

If a match is found alert is raises. The variable in which the `left div span` was stored is then `appended` to the `right side div`.

```js
    var tomove;
    var selected;
    $('span').click(function(){tomove=$(this).text();selected=$(this)})
    $("button").click(function(){

selected.remove();
var t=$('#right > span');
var str=$(t).text().toString();
var arr=str.split('');
   var txt=$(selected).text().toString();
console.log(txt)

    if(arr.includes(txt))
    {
        alert("Duplicates aren't allowed!")
    }
else
{  $("#right").append(selected);}

  

    })
```

```css
 div{

            border-color: blue;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
        span
        {
            border-color:green;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
        }
        #right
        {
            margin-left:100px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
       
</head>
<body id="body">
    <div id="left">
<span>a</span><br>
<span>s</span><br>
<span>d</span><br>
<span>f</span><br>
<span>g</span><br>

    </div>
    <div id="right">
            <span>e</span><br>
            <span>r</span><br>
            <span>g</span><br>
            <span>w</span><br>
            <span>g</span><br>

    </div>
    <button id="move">Move</button>
    
   </body>
   
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.... i can use this but problem is the selected fields  is just moving but not storing inside array if it stores in array then we can use this format other than that duplicate values all other selected fields are storing inside array

Comment: i am getting alert message but still the duplicate value is moving to 2nd column check this http://jsfiddle.net/zwc5b0p8/

Comment: Check now! Forgot to put an else